# CDN with WordPress 4

Tags: wordpress

How can I setup a self hosted CDN with WordPress 4. I couldn't find any settings link related to this in WP Admin panel.

```
Domain: www.example.com
CDN: files.example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is w3-total-cache plugin that has build in options for CDN
https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Answer (score -1):

There are also many plugins available on Wordpress plugin's repository that will help you to integrate CDN with wordpress or check here : http://www.wpoptimus.com/740/best-wordpress-plugins-integrate-cdn/

Comment: Settings > Miscellaneous Settings has been remove from Wordpress4

Comment: Okay then you need to use a plugin for it.